# How to force install .NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I just cloned my repository, which I created on my other PC, and it appears the .NET Framework was set to 4.5.2. I have 4.6.2 on this current PC, and I get the following error when I try to launch the project:

[image]

I have tried to install 4.5.2, but it says I already have it installed, or another, newer installation is already installed.

If I edit my Project.csproj file and change `TargetFrameworkVersion` from `v4.5.2` to `v4.6.2` I get the same error. If I change it to 4.5 (which is appears I have on my PC as well), I get a lot of reference errors in my project, which I have to manually go edit. Some of them appears not to work with 4.5, as they were introduced in 4.5.2, so that's definitely not an option.

What on earth do I do?

Comment: So when you said you "tried to install" what did you do? did you choose the middle option from the dialog you showed us?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah I selected the middle option, but ended up grabbing the standalone offline installer for 4.5.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You of course can have the runtime installed already, but Visual Studio is asking for the Developer Pack,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2901951/the-microsoft-.net-framework-4.5.2-developer-pack-for-windows-server-2012-r2,-windows-8.1,-windows-server-2012,-windows-8,-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1,-windows-7-sp1,-windows-server-2008-sp2,-and-windows-vista-sp2

If you don't know that, now you should.

Update: Many .NET Framework versions went end of life recently, so you can only find the remaining in https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, this was a huge pain in the ass last night.

Comment: both these links are dead, backup versions would be nice if somebody knows reputable mirrors.

Comment: All the devpacks can now be downloaded from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk